# Error while using MongoDB command

Tags: mongodb

I am trying to start working with MongoDB but when i installed it and tried to set up path for DB and logs i got error.

Commend used:  mongod --directoryperdb --dbpath G:\MongoDB\data\db\ --logpath G:\MongoDB\data\log\mongo.log --logap
pend --install

Error: 2018-08-05T18:54:47.346+0200 I CONTROL  [main] Automatically disabling TLS 1.0, to force-enable TLS 1.0 specify --sslDis
abledProtocols 'none'

System: Windows10

I use Windows PowerShell.

I did try to add "--sslDisabledProtocols none"

but that made new error appear:

BadValue: need to enable SSL via the sslMode flag when using SSL configuration parameters
try 'G:\MongoDB\bin\mongod.exe --help' for more information

Which this time throws me --help ... :P I am reading trought it but maybe one of you guys had similar error?

Comment: Run CMD as administrator and try the same command, try to created mongodb as a service eg. "mongod --port 27017 --dbpath "C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\4.0\data" --logpath="C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\4.0\log\mongod.log" --install --serviceName "mongodb"" and then run net start mongodb.

Answer (score 2):

That error is not important. The important thing is if you can run MongoDB. If you have service called 'MongoDB Server' in your services, remove it and then run the script you wrote here, error is fine, try to start by command "net start MongoDB"

Answer (score 2):

Step 01 :
Go to "c" drive

Step 02 :
Create a new folder and rename it as data

Step 03 :
Go to inside you created data folder and create a new folder and rename it as db

step 04 :
Go to cmd and run mongod

Thanks,